# How to resize video in GitHub

Tags: github

How do I resize my video in GitHub markdown? For example, I drag and drop a video into the markdown and got this link but I would like to resize my video.

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/16434638/125166121-088f0e80-e192-11eb-8210-7245b1fe4f62.mp4

Comment: Did you get a solution to this? I am facing the same problem and would like to know a way of resizing the uploaded video.

Comment: As per https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/27715 there isn't a resolution yet. Currently github is not supporting custom video dimensions on README.

Answer (score -1):

The syntax isn't easy to remember if you don't use it often, but here you go, with the link you provided:

`<img src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/16434638/125166121-088f0e80-e192-11eb-8210-7245b1fe4f62.mp4" width="200">`

You could also specify the `height` instead of the `width`, or both.

Answer (score -1):

Resizing the original video is one option, e.g. https://online-video-cutter.com/resize-video

Though I'm also looking for something like `<img src="" width="">`.

Comment: What this answer adds to previous?

Comment: @Farid A working solution? `<img` doesn't work on videos. Since many platforms resize embeds to max width, it's not obvious that resizing the video would work.